# magento product collection

Tags: magento

In extention I'm getting product collection on catalog_product_view page like this:

```
if (!$product = Mage::registry('product')) {
    return new Varien_Data_Collection();
}
$category = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Category();
$category->load($product->getCategoryId());
$collection = $category->getProductCollection();
```

and how can I add additional attributes to this collection?

for example I can't get something like this

```
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('manufacturer');
```

I wish to add some attribute by code (not id, because this may be different attributes added in layout) and then group data by this attribute

thnx

Answer (score 1):

You could instantiate a product collection and filter it instead of getting the products of a specific category directly:

```
if (!$product = Mage::registry('product')) {
    return new Varien_Data_Collection();
}
// get a product collection and filter it by category
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection->addCategoryFilter($product->getCategoryId());
// add the attributes you need
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('manufacturer');
$collection->setOrder('manufacturer', 'asc');
// load the collection and return it
$collection->load();
return $collection;
```

Be careful: You can not add attributes to the collection after loading it!
Additionally, you do not have to explicitely call `load()` - the collection will be loaded on demand.

Hope this helps.

Comment: this will work with flat, but not w/o it as I understent - I tried this. But I can't enable flat structure because there over 500 attributes for products and server configuration doesn't allow this

Comment: I am not sure if this works without flat. Anyway, I guess this is not the only problem you get if flat is disabled / your server is too slow. Magento has to run on a good infrastructure.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('manufacturer')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); ?>
```